# Chosen jQuery not working perfect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen jQuery with select box. It's is working but it's displays two dropdown instead of one. I just need only one dropdown which has search option and no need of old dropdown.

my code is

```js
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
  no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="chosen-select">
  <option value="1">Testing1</option>
  <option value="2">Testing2</option>
  <option value="3">Testing3</option>
  <option value="4">Testing4</option>
</select>
```

But I am getting two dropdown one is default and another with chosen functionality. I don't need default dropdown to display it should hide by applying chosen JavaScript.

Thank You

Comment: I have created a snippet, can you reproduce the issue

Comment: @Rajan Singh may the other functionality on page is breaking your code. The provided code looks okay.

Comment: thanx @sangram parmar, I am checking other things

Answer (score 0):

It May be possible use onchange function jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.chosen-select').on('change', function() {
          alert("Oops, nothing found!");
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: but I need dropdown when page load. and it remove dropdown which have chosen functionility